# (Roblox Studio/Lua) How do I place 2 random gears from game.Workspace.items into player.Backpack everytime they spawn or respawn?

Tags: random, lua, roblox

I need a script in Roblox Studio (Lua code) that places two random gears from the folder
`game.Workspace.items` into the player's backpack (    `player.Backpack` I think)

I tried this code and it did nothing:

```
`
    local Players = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
repeat task.wait() until Players.Character
local backpack = Players.Backpack
local ReplStor = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local servstorTools = {ReplStor.AduritePeriastron, 
ReplStor.AmethystPeriastron, ReplStor.BlackIronPeriastron, 
ReplStor.BlackPeriastron, ReplStor.BlizzariaPeriastron, 
ReplStor.BrownPeriastron, ReplStor.CHAOSPeriastron, 
ReplStor.ChrysocollaPeriastron, ReplStor.CrescendoPeriastron, 
ReplStor.DoomPeriastron, ReplStor.DualAzurePeriastron, 
ReplStor.FallPeriastron, ReplStor.FestivePeriastron, 
ReplStor.FuchsiaPeriastron, ReplStor.FuryPeriastronAfi, 
ReplStor.GoldenPeriastron, ReplStor.GrimgoldPeriastron, 
ReplStor.HazelPeriastron, ReplStor.LightningPeriastron, 
ReplStor.OrangePeriastronMu, ReplStor.PeriastronAstra, 
ReplStor.RainbowStarPeriastron, ReplStor.RainbowPeriastron, 
ReplStor.RedPeriastron, ReplStor.GreenPeriastron, 
ReplStor.SpringStormPeriastron, ReplStor.SuperPeriastron, 
ReplStor.TimePeriastron, ReplStor.TitaniumPeriastron, 
ReplStor.UltraCrimsonPeriastron, ReplStor.UltraPeriastron, 
ReplStor.ZygrainbowPeriastron }
local randIndex = math.random(1, #servstorTools)
local backpack = Players.LocalPlayer:FindFirstChildOfClass("Backpack")

if backpack then
    for i = 1,3 do
        servstorTools[randIndex]:Clone().Parent = backpack
        wait(2)
    end

end
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You redeclared backpack incorrectly and randindex should be generated twice, so just place it inside the loop. The tools should be inside the replicatedstorage and localscript inside the starterCharacterScripts.

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
repeat task.wait() until Players.Character
local backpack = Players.Backpack
local ReplStor = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local servstorTools = {ReplStor.AduritePeriastron, 
ReplStor.AmethystPeriastron, ReplStor.BlackIronPeriastron, 
ReplStor.BlackPeriastron, ReplStor.BlizzariaPeriastron, 
ReplStor.BrownPeriastron, ReplStor.CHAOSPeriastron, 
ReplStor.ChrysocollaPeriastron, ReplStor.CrescendoPeriastron, 
ReplStor.DoomPeriastron, ReplStor.DualAzurePeriastron, 
ReplStor.FallPeriastron, ReplStor.FestivePeriastron, 
ReplStor.FuchsiaPeriastron, ReplStor.FuryPeriastronAfi, 
ReplStor.GoldenPeriastron, ReplStor.GrimgoldPeriastron, 
ReplStor.HazelPeriastron, ReplStor.LightningPeriastron, 
ReplStor.OrangePeriastronMu, ReplStor.PeriastronAstra, 
ReplStor.RainbowStarPeriastron, ReplStor.RainbowPeriastron, 
ReplStor.RedPeriastron, ReplStor.GreenPeriastron, 
ReplStor.SpringStormPeriastron, ReplStor.SuperPeriastron, 
ReplStor.TimePeriastron, ReplStor.TitaniumPeriastron, 
ReplStor.UltraCrimsonPeriastron, ReplStor.UltraPeriastron, 
ReplStor.ZygrainbowPeriastron}

if backpack then
    for i = 1,2 do
        servstorTools[math.random(1, #servstorTools)]:Clone().Parent = backpack
        wait(2)
    end
end
```